# A confusion about an assumption in the setting of the local family index theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, index-theory

Let $\pi:M\to B$ be a proper submersion with closed, oriented and spin fibers. Then one can state the local family index theorem as an equality of differential forms (ignoring the details here).

I am confused with an assumption on the manifolds $M$ and $B$. Usually they are assumed to be compact to make sure certain convergence results (and many papers in the field of local index theory do make such an assumption). My question is does the local family index theorem still hold if $M$ and $B$ are noncompact? If I am not mistaken, in Chapter 10 of the book "Heat kernels and Dirac operators" by Berline-Getzler-Vergne, they did not assume $M$ and $B$ are compact.

I would like to think it does, as we can take an increasing sequence $(B_i)$ of compact embedded submanifolds with boundary of $B$ of codimension zero whose union is $B$, and then define $M_i=\pi^{-1}(B_i)$ for each $i$. Then the sequence $(M_i)$ has the same property and whose union is $M$. The local family index theorem surely holds for $\pi_i:M_i\to B_i$. Since $\Omega(B)=\varprojlim\Omega(B_i)$ and the objects are "compatible" with restriction on smaller manifolds, hopefully this argument is fine.

Please let me know if I am correct or wrong.

Comment: I believe you are absolutely right.

Comment: @SebastianGoette But if we don't assume $B$ is compact, does the kernel bundle exist even if we assume the family of kernel $\{\ker(D_b)\}$ has (locally) constant dimension? or we can construct something like a kernel bundle by clutching construction?

Comment: Being a bundle is a local property, so I don't see any problems, as long as $B$ is locally compact.

Comment: @SebastianGoette Ok. Thanks a lot.